# GRUB - NOT dual booting, why does it still show up by default?

Tags: linux, grub

I googled and searched the exchange for answers, it seems most questions are just asking how to disable it.  why is the loader still popping the menu up despite only having Xubuntu installed? Also, it shows windows 10 recovery although I completely formatted my drives through the Xubuntu installer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking '*why do you see the GRUB menu when booting*', that is it is configured to show the menu. You can change this as I am sure you have seen elsewhere.

If you are asking '*why do you see grub at all*', it is because most linux distributions use grub as the [boot loader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booting#Modern_boot_loaders). I believe this is what Xubuntu uses. Grub is not just for systems that dual boot.

As to '*why the boot loader seems to recognize non-existent OS's on your PC*', it is an indication that the must have been recognized by grub in the past. You can remove them as you are aware. The process is somewhat different if you are using the UEFI version of the grub boot loader as you may need to remove the UEFI boot remnants of windoze before it will disappear from grub completely.

Comment: hey datUser thank you for clarifying my ambiguity and answering them, this really helps.

Comment: @fool You are welcome. Feel free to mark this answer as correct if it addressed your needs adequately.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the file

```
/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

and delete Windows OS entry You don't use anymore